# Laravel connect to sqlite: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I'am trying to connect a Laravel API to a sqlite file. But when i try to access a controller- method this error is given:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Here is my .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=xxxx
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=xxxx

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite


REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

And my config\database.php:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('my-database.db'),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my-database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],
```

Does anyone have a clue what is wrong in my configuration?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `sqlite` installed? Does the database `my-database.db` exist? Have you checked the permissions of the file?

Comment: Is your config cached?  That doesn't sound like a sqlite error.

Comment: Thank you. I feel quite dumb right now. clear cache solved it....